# Unable to encrypting files after moving gpg2 keys

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I have created gpg2 keys in one machine under my user name and I was succesful in encryption and decryption.

Now I had to move those keys to another machine under a different user. This new user on the other machine can only be sudo'd , can not be logged in.

After moving when I perform list keys it works fine and list all keys, but when I attempt to encrypt I get "You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user:.... " and the then nothing happens. I used to get the same message on the old machine but it continued and completed the encryption. On the new machine it simply hangs.

FYI .. the encryption command I am using is ..

/usr/bin/gpg2 --compress-algo 1 --cipher-algo cast5 --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --recipient "user@user" --local-user anotheruser@anotheruser --output testfile.gpg2 -se testfile.txt < passwordfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Adding GPG_TTY=$(tty);export GPG_TTY resolved the issue